# Range Selector in Are Graph of High Chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, date-range

I am using the Highchart to draw charts of my data.I have seen the [date range](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/range-selector) selector in this chart but I am using [Area Graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line) but range selector is not coming in this.Following is my code.

```
jQuery('#weenat_statr_chart').highcharts({

                title: {
                    text: chart_title
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },

                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true,
                    valueSuffix: unit_value
                },

                legend: {
                },
,
                rangeSelector: {
                    buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                        fill: 'none',
                        stroke: 'none',
                        'stroke-width': 0,
                        r: 8,
                        style: {
                            color: '#039',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                            },
                            select: {
                                fill: '#039',
                                style: {
                                    color: 'white'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    labelStyle: {
                        color: 'silver',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    selected: 1
                },              
                series: [{
                    name: unit_name,
                    data: averages,
                    zIndex: 1,
                    marker: {
                        fillColor: 'white',
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    name: '<?php echo __("Range","test-plugin"); ?>',
                    data: ranges,
                    type: 'arearange',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    linkedTo: ':previous',
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                    fillOpacity: 0.3,
                    zIndex: 0
                }]
            });
```

[js fiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/73sox4ws/)

Please help me how to use date range with Area graph.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a live demo like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RaeenHashemi here is the jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/73sox4ws/

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because **`rangeSelector`** is for **HighStock** only and not highcharts. So you need to change your script to:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

And add **`StockChart`** word to the function creating the chart:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', { ... } );
```

Here's the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/73sox4ws/1/)

Comment: No this is not the answer at all. As I already told in my question that it is for stockchart but I am using Area Graph, please note that.

Comment: So what? Its the same except it has a navigator which you can disable. The yAxis is opposite which you can correct. Markers are not shown without hover which also can be fixed - http://jsfiddle.net/73sox4ws/3/ What now? All good?

Comment: yeah... thank you so much it worked. Only one point can you tell me which parameter is needed to show bubbles on chart. I cant see bubbles on chart. thanks

Comment: In highstock markers are disabled without hover. Inside `Series.marker` set the `enabled : true` and also set the `radius : 4` and you can change it to have different size of bubbles.

Comment: Thank you Raeen now everything is setup :) but suddenly one another point changed in graph. Now the y-axis is coming on the right hand side while it was on the left hand side previously.Can you please help me in this.

Comment: No problem. Set **`opposite: false`** in yAxis and also **`showLastLabel: true`** because sometimes it won't show the last label in highstock.

Comment: No problem mate, the real geniuses are the developers who wrote it ;)

Comment: yes absolutely. Brother I have one more question related to chart but not of the above question. If you can answer that would be great. As you can see in range section at the below there is an area of time on the x-axis. Can I cover it in some border ?

Comment: Actually you must ask it as another question, because it is not related to this question. And I don't get what you mean exactly. Maybe ask a question and post a picture or demo to show it.